# Instantiate an Interface using unknown but derived type

Tags: c#, interface

I would like to instantiate an interface using an unknown class but this class implements the interface.
I really don't have a clue how to do it. The closest thing I have found is:

```
IClientHandler handler = (IClientHandler)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
```

Which doesn't work.

handler is an interface and T is some class that derives from a base class (ClientBase) which implements IClientHandler.
I would like to pass the type of T at run time.

Comment: make a constraint for `T`: `class MyClass<T> where T : IClientHandler`. That should do a trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a type constaint to `T` that requires it to implement `IClientHandler`. You could even add a `new()` constraint to require the type `T` to have a default constructor, so you could avoid having to use `Activator.CreateInstance` and just create a new object directly:

```
public void SomeMethod<T> ()
    where T : IClientHandler, new()
{
    IClientHandler handler = new T();
    // do stuff
}
```